# Flowtype does not recognize type errors

Tags: flowtype, create-react-app, nuclide-editor

I set up an app using create-react-app, and am trying to use Flow.

1. Installed Flow
2. Installed Nuclide
3. Created an empty .flowconfig with flow init in the project
4. Used `/* @flow */` in a file, and intentionally added a type error.

When I run flow check from the project directory, or when I'm looking at the file in Atom/Nuclide, it's incorrectly registering as 'no errors'.

However, it DOES correctly show the types when I hover over the variable, and it's correctly marking covered and uncovered sections of the file.

I have checked the path to Flow, and it seems correct. I have tried selecting 'Use flow binary' and that didn't change the behavior.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-bin": "^0.48.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow"
  }
}
```

My error to check:
[image: string = 2]

It seems to run but says 'No errors!' (npm run flow, flow, or flow status) or 'Found 0 errors' (flow check).

The file I am checking is a .js file. It is shown when I run 'flow ls'.

I have tried stopping and restarting the server.

**EDIT:**
Working!
I changed my npm script in package.json to "flow": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2", and I moved // @flow to absolute top of the file, versus just above the code I wanted to check.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong. Try using `flow ls` to make sure that the file in question is shown. What is the extension of the file you are trying to check?

Comment: I believe I had a similar issue previously, I think I was able to fix it by running `flow stop` and then `flow start` to restart the flow server and then i restarted the editor.